# transition-delay for pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

As you see in code below I used pseudo element `after` to get triangle shape for the menu item.

Why is the triangle not responding to the transition at all?

```css
.breadcrumb { 
    list-style: none; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

.breadcrumb li { 
    float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10px 0 10px 65px;
    background: brown;                   /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1); 
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }

.breadcrumb li a:hover { background: hsla(34,85%,25%,1); transition-delay:.3s; }
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,25%,1) !important; transition: border-color 0.3s ; }
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Camper Vans</a></li>
</ul>
```

Credit: This menu taken from lesson on css-tricks.com with some editing.

Comment: You have a typo (`borded`) in the last line of your CSS but it's not clear me what you are trying to do.

Comment: what i want to get is the transition apply to both `a` and `pseud class`... in my case only `a` gets transition, for now.

Comment: What is the delay for?

Comment: sorry for mistake in writing `border`. i change it but still not working

Comment: delay is for `after` pseudo class

Comment: Ok..see answer below. BTW `:after` is a pseudo-element...not a pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your CSS and also an incorrect property

Your code

```
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
    transition: borded-color 0.3s;
}
```

should look like this

```
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/espz84tb/10/)